# Ubuntu One verification image never loads

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I am trying to create a Ubuntu One account but the verification image just keeps loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://one.ubuntu.com/

try to create your account from your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you already created the account from the web browser then you can login using it.
If you don't get the verification image on the web browser, that would indicate some problem accessing recaptcha (the image's provider) from your network.